# Update a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, frame

I have two internalframes Operation and showOperation inside one JFrame, I would like to know how to update showOperation after making  things of Operation, for example:

i have tried this

```
showOperation.repaint();
```

but doesn' t works, i have tried also

```
showOperation.dispose();
```

and after

```
 showOperation.setVisible(true);
```

but doesn' t works
how i can update this internalframe?

---

more details,

i have this class

```
public class ShowAssistance {
public static JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
         .
         . 
         .

public ShowAssistance() {
    showProducts();
}
    public void showProducts(){
    //add the internalframe to the mainframe of the application as explained above
    mainFrame.getframe().add(frame);
   }
```

and this class when i use to update the internalframe

```
public class update{
update(){
  showMeUpdate();
  } public void showMeUpdate(){
    //after some  operations i do
          ShowAssistance.frame.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit frustrating for us since you're leaving out much critical information. Please help us help you by providing more information and code, preferably an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check out the link).

Comment: Please see edit to my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to your problem is I believe likely to be one of references, but I can't tell for sure since the information that you have given us so far is **very** limited. Likely the one class does not have a valid reference to the ***displayed*** instance of the other class, meaning that you are possibly calling methods on a non-displayed object. If so, the key is to pass that reference in via a setter method or constructor parameter. The details of a solution will depend on the details and code of the problem.

So if you need more help, please provide us with much more relevant information and relevant code, preferably an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check the link).

---

**Edit**
Regarding your recent additions to your question:

- Your frame variable should not be static. This is not likely causing your problem, but will likely cause significant problems later on. Make it an instance variable and give the class methods to set it, to change its state, and to extract its state.
- Your `showMeUpdate()` method calls `repaint()` on the JInternalFrame object, but you don't show us why you think that this will do anything of importance. A call to `repaint()` should not change the *state* of a component, but should only allow the component to re-draw itself and change its appearance due to some other previous change in state. Again, your question remains short of essential details. The more relevant information that you can give us (without overwhelming us with irrelevant information) the better we will be equipped to help.
- You will want to learn and abide by Java naming convention: Java class names should begin with an upper case letter and method and variable names with lower case letters. This may seem trivial to you now, but by following these conventions, others (us!) who are reading your code will understand it better and quicker, and be able to give you better help.
- Your code is not close to the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) standard. The closer you adhere to this standard, the better we can understand your code and your problem.

Comment: i know the java convenctions,i extrapolated i very tiny code of a very large class,with begin with upper case letter,anyway thanks you

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're wanting to reorganise the components. If so, you could try the [revalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate%28%29) method. If this does not achieve the desired result, we need more information.